# How to plot $z=\exp \left(-r^2\right) (\sin (6 \pi r)-r \cos (3 \theta ))$?

Tags: plotting

Having seen the following plot on a page, I am trying to recreate it with Mathematica. [image]

I have defined the function and used `Plot3D` to create the plot as the following commands shows.

```
z = Exp[-r^2]*(Sin[6 Pi r] - r Cos[3 θ])
Plot3D[z, {r, -8, 8}, {θ, -8, 8}]
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Why do I have two different plots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 E^-r^2 (Sin[6 \[Pi] r] - r Cos[3 \[Theta]]),
     {r, 0, 1}, 
     {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]